# Batch script reverse content of text file change load order and reverse again

Tags: batch-file, cmd

```
set startpath=%cd%
del mods.txt
del mod.txt
del prioritys.txt
del desiredmodname.txt
type NUL > prioritys.txt
cls
set /p w3folder=<w3folder.txt
if not exist "%w3folder%\content\content0" (goto choosew3folder) else goto       askmodkitfolder
:choosew3folder
OpenFolderBox.exe C:\ "Appears only on first start or path edit - Please choose your The Witcher 3 Wild Hunt Directory" > w3folder.txt
set /p w3folder=<w3folder.txt
:askmodkitfolder
set /p modkitfolder=<modkitfolder.txt
if not exist "%modkitfolder%\bin\config\base" (goto choosemodkitfolder) else goto askbasefolder
:choosemodkitfolder
OpenFolderBox.exe C:\ "Appears only on first start or path edit - Please choose your Official ModKit Directory" > modkitfolder.txt
set /p modkitfolder=<modkitfolder.txt
:askbasefolder
set /p w3basefolder=<w3basefolder.txt
if not exist "%w3basefolder%\gameplay\community" (goto choosebasefolder) else goto :selectmods
:choosebasefolder
MessageBox.exe "In the next Window you have to select your uncooked base game folder - click on cancel if u dont have it or if u dont know what im talking about :D" "First start/Changed base folder" "OK" "Information" "Button1" "None" "30"
OpenFolderBox.exe C:\ "choose game base folder-cancel to uncook base game" > w3basefolder.txt
set /p w3basefolder=<w3basefolder.txt
Call notEmpty.bat w3basefolder.txt
If %errorlevel% EQU 0 (goto selectmods) Else (goto uncookbase)
:uncookbase
MKDIR "%startpath%\base"
cd "%w3folder%\xTcTools\bin\x64\"
call wcc_lite.exe uncook -indir="%w3folder%\content" -outdir="%startpath%\base"
call wcc_lite.exe uncook -indir="%w3folder%\DLC" -outdir="%startpath%\base"
set w3basefolder="%startpath%\base"
:selectmods
cd "%startpath%"
del mod.txt
del modname.txt
type NUL > mod.txt
type NUL > modname.txt
call OpenFolderBox.exe "%w3folder%\mods" "Choose next mod - press cancel to uncook selected mods" >> mod.txt
Call notEmpty.bat mod.txt
If %errorlevel% EQU 0 (goto findrepl) Else (goto uncookmods)
:findrepl
set /p mod=< mod.txt
call modname.bat "%mod%"
cd "%startpath%"
echo %modname% >> prioritys.txt
timeout 1
type "mod.txt"|findrepl /i /o:1:1 >>"mods.txt"
goto selectmods
:uncookmods
set /p uncookmod=< mods.txt
call modname.bat "%uncookmod%"
cd "%modkitfolder%\bin\x64\"
call wcc_lite.exe uncook -indir="%uncookmod%" -outdir="%startpath%\mods\%modname%"
if not exist "%startpath%\%modname%" (goto quickbms) else goto askmod
:quickbms
cd "%startpath%"
call quickbms.exe -d -o -Y "%startpath%\witcher3.bms" "%uncookmod%\content\blob0.bundle" "%startpath%\%modname%"
call quickbms.exe -d -o -Y "%startpath%\witcher3.bms" "%uncookmod%\content\blob1.bundle" "%startpath%\%modname%"
call quickbms.exe -d -o -Y "%startpath%\witcher3.bms" "%uncookmod%\content\blob2.bundle" "%startpath%\%modname%"
call quickbms.exe -d -o -Y "%startpath%\witcher3.bms" "%uncookmod%\content\buffers0.bundle" "%startpath%\%modname%"
call quickbms.exe -d -o -Y "%startpath%\witcher3.bms" "%uncookmod%\content\buffers1.bundle" "%startpath%\%modname%"
call quickbms.exe -d -o -Y "%startpath%\witcher3.bms" "%uncookmod%\content\buffers2.bundle" "%startpath%\%modname%"
Robocopy.exe /MOVE /S /E "%startpath%\%modname%\blob0.bundle" "%startpath%\mods\%modname%"
Robocopy.exe /MOVE /S /E "%startpath%\%modname%\blob1.bundle" "%startpath%\mods\%modname%"
Robocopy.exe /MOVE /S /E "%startpath%\%modname%\blob2.bundle" "%startpath%\mods\%modname%"
Robocopy.exe /MOVE /S /E "%startpath%\%modname%\buffers0.bundle" "%startpath%\mods\%modname%"
Robocopy.exe /MOVE /S /E "%startpath%\%modname%\buffers1.bundle" "%startpath%\mods\%modname%"
Robocopy.exe /MOVE /S /E "%startpath%\%modname%\buffers2.bundle" "%startpath%\mods\%modname%"
rd /s /q "%startpath%\%modname%"
:askmod
MKDIR "%w3folder%\mods\00_MergedMods"
move "%uncookmod%" "%w3folder%\mods\00_MergedMods"
cd "%startpath%"
timeout 1
type "mods.txt"|findrepl /v /o:1:1 >"mods.txt"
Call notEmpty.bat mods.txt
If %errorlevel% EQU 0 (goto uncookmods) Else (goto editfiles)
:editfiles
DROPDOWNBOX.exe "Edit Load Order;Edit Files;Build Mod" "What you like to do?" "Option" /RI /C:23 >NUL
SET ReturnCode=%ErrorLevel%
IF "%ReturnCode%"=="0" goto editfiles
IF "%ReturnCode%"=="1" cmd /c "prioritys.txt"
IF "%ReturnCode%"=="2" %SystemRoot%\explorer.exe "%startpath%\mods"
IF "%ReturnCode%"=="3" goto robocopy
goto editfiles
:robocopy
set /p modtocopy=< prioritys.txt
echo %modtocopy% >> IncludedMods.txt
Robocopy.exe /MOVE /S /E "%startpath%\mods\%modtocopy%" "%startpath%\uncook"
timeout 1
type "prioritys.txt"|findrepl /v /o:1:1 >"prioritys.txt"
Call notEmpty.bat prioritys.txt
If %errorlevel% EQU 0 (goto robocopy) Else (goto build)
:build
rd /s /q "%startpath%\mods"
InputBox.exe "Enter Name to start building Mod" "Enter Name and Build Mod" "mod" > desiredmodname.txt
set /p desiredmodname=< desiredmodname.txt
MKDIR "%startpath%\%desiredmodname%\content"
MKDIR "%startpath%\cooked"
cd "%modkitfolder%\bin\x64\"
call wcc_lite.exe cook -platform=pc -mod="%startpath%\uncook" -basedir="D:\Spiele\Witcher3Mods\Base" -outdir="%startpath%\cooked"
call wcc_lite.exe buildcache textures -basedir="%startpath%\uncook" -platform=pc -db="%startpath%\cooked\cook.db" -out="%startpath%\%desiredmodname%\content\texture.cache"
call wcc_lite.exe pack -dir="%startpath%\cooked" -outdir="%startpath%\%desiredmodname%\content"
call wcc_lite.exe metadatastore -path="%startpath%\%desiredmodname%\content"
cd "%startpath%"
rd /s /q "%startpath%\cooked"
rd /s /q "%startpath%\uncook"
move "IncludedMods.txt" "%startpath%\%desiredmodname%"
del mods.txt
del mod.txt
del modname.txt
del prioritys.txt
del desiredmodname.txt
move "%startpath%\%desiredmodname%" "%w3folder%\mods"
MessageBox.exe "All Done enjoy Witcher 3 Wild Hunt now!" "Mod Build Success" "OK" "Information" "Button1" "None" "10"
exit
```

So this is my code. Everything works fine. Now at the editlines part i give the choice to edit a load order file that looks like this:

```
modWEATHER  
modInventoryBackground  
modTest1
modTest2
modTest3
modTest4
modTest5
```

is there a way in batch to reverse this file (because i want the prioritys normal like 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 etc but the script later need it in a reversed way because the process itself need it reversed later, because the last loaded files can replace the first  loaded files. (bad english sorry)

so is there a way to reverse this loadorder.txt file give it to the user let him change something and reverse again after?

and in line 84 i pass this loadorder file to the user but it got openened with his standart text editor. Is there a small tool to let the user change load orders of this text file? 
i hope you understand.

Comment: loadorder file has one name in every line without spaces. it look wierd above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another method based on `sort` command:

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "n=2000000"
for /F "usebackq tokens=1*" %%a in (`
   (echo off ^& for /F "usebackq delims=" %%c in ("%~1"^) do (
   set /A "n-=1" ^& echo %%n%% %%c^)^) ^| sort`) do echo %%b
```

The modification below allows to include blank lines:

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "n=2000000"
for /F "usebackq tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in (`
   (echo off ^& for /F "delims=" %%c in ('findstr /N "^" "%~1"'^) do (
   set /A "n-=1" ^& echo %%n%% %%c^)^) ^| sort`) do echo(%%b
```

To generate an output file, just enclose *the whole* `for /F` command in parentheses and redirect the output to a file. After that, you may replace the original file with the output:

```
(for /F "usebackq tokens=1*" %%a in (`... sort`) do echo %%b) > output.txt
move /Y output.txt "%~1"
```

Comment: I am afraid this will remove any leading colons `:`... anyway, I like this approach...

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a batch file to reverse a File.
It uses recursion and some other ugly tricks, but it seems to work:

***File: Reverse.bat***

```
@echo off 
set LineCount=0
for /F %%a in (%1) do (set /A LineCount+=1)
call :ReverseFile %1
exit /B

:ReverseFile [%1|Filename] [%2|LineCount]
    SetLocal
    set /A LineCount-=1
    if %LineCount%==-1 exit /B
    set SKIP_CMD="skip=%LineCount%"
    if %LineCount%==0 set SKIP_CMD=
    for /F %SKIP_CMD% %%a in (%1) do (set Line=%%a & echo(%%a & call :ReverseFile %1 %LineCount% & exit /B)
exit /B
```

---

***Example Usage***

***File: TestData.txt***

```
Four
score
and
seven
years
ago
our
fathers
brought
forth
on
this
continent
```

```
C:\BatchFiles> Reverse TestData.txt
continent
this
on
forth
brought
fathers
our
ago
years
seven
and
score
Four
```

Comment: Thats what im talking about :D Both Methods work well thank you. 

To the load order part. This should be a noob tool - easy for everyone. 

I think this could be possible:

Show the lines of a text file in the cmd window and navigate throw the lines by arrow keys and using + and - to put on line up or down?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a subroutine taking 2 filenames as parameters, reversing the first file into the second:

```dos
:reverse
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
:: remove variables starting $
FOR  /F "delims==" %%a In ('set $ 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%a="
SET /a line=9999
FOR  /F "usebackq delims=" %%a In ("%~1") DO SET "$!line!=%%a"&SET /a line-=1
(
 FOR  /F "tokens=1*delims==" %%a In ('set $ 2^>Nul') DO ECHO(%%b
)>"%~2"
GOTO :eof
```

It works by building the file contents into variables `$9999`, `$9998` etc, then listing them into the new file. It's essential that the initial setting of `line` is sufficiently large that subtracting the number of lines in the file from its initial setting does not change the number of digits in the value (here 4, so will work with up to 8,999 lines in theory as 9999-8999 = 1000; 1 more and it makes 999 which is 3 digits)

Could be set up as a separate batch if required.

`Notepad` could no doubt be called to edit the file.

```
notepad "newfilename"
```

will invoke notepad and wait until the user saves any changes before proceeding.